# Is there no capitalize button in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, text, tools

I do not see an option to set a phrase as uppercase with the click of the button. Is there no such feature, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

Mine is in the Menu Extensions > Text.

Comment: Additionally, Wyatt might be interested to know that one can set a keyboard shortcut for extensions in Edit > Preferences > Interface > Keyboard shortcuts.